# SICP stream integrator

Tags: scheme, sicp

In SICP chapter 3.5 the code for a integrator is given

```scheme
(define (solve f y0 dt)
  (define y (integral dy y0 dt))
  (define dy (stream-map f y))
  y)
```

> a signal-processing system for solving the differential equation dy/dt=f(y)
> where f
> is a given function. The figure shows a mapping component, which applies f
> to its input signal, linked in a feedback loop to an integrator in a manner very similar to that of the analog computer circuits that are actually used to solve such equations.

What is the real life useage of the given program?

Comment: It's not in 5.4 but in 3.5. The real-life usage is to numerically solve the mentioned differential equation.

Comment: In the SICP videos they say a high percentage of all algorithms can be replaced with using streams. Streams are just a way to do lazy eval in an eager language. Streams are just a way to do abstraction where you in the language gets to do things on the whole set in series but when it is used it does it in parallell (by need)